# Intellij gradle import Issue

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I'm having a lot of issues w/ my intellij project to recognize 3rd party libraries I've imported with gradle. Let me outline some steps I've tried.

1. The code compiles properly in the terminal.
2. Invalidating and restarting intellij does nothing.
3. The import, seems to be in the project dependency folder.
4. I've tried removing the import and resyncing gradle, then adding it back in.
5. Tried deleting the intellij app and re-installing (I think I may have done this wrong given my configurations were saved upon re-download).
6. I've tried unticking offline mode, and doing all this in gradlew preferences.
7. I've tried increasing memory allocation in both intellij and for gradle.
8. No one else on my team seems to be having this issue.

I have no idea what else to try or where to look. Would LOVE some pointers. Happy to edit. Thanks!

Intellij Version: 2019.1.3

Comment: How exactly are you importing them?  As dependencies or something...else?

Comment: yup as a dependency!

Comment: Please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the [logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) and a [sample project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).